# Right way of creating a export module in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create a module which will fetch all entries of a table from DB.
I could do it in below two manners -

1st -

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var results = <<feteched results from DB>>
module.exports = function(req,res){
    res.render("myview", results);
}
```

2nd -

```
module.exports = function(req,res){
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var results = <<feteched results from DB>>
    res.render("myview", results);
}
```

In my routes file, I import this module and execute it like this -

```
var myfunc = require('../db/myfunc');
router.get('/article/:article', function(req, res) {
        myfunc(req,res);
    });
```

Both 1st and 2nd works. I have two questions -

1. Are both approaches exactly same or is there any difference in underneath how they work?
2. which one should be preferred for writing code, i.e should we wrap everything (requires and business logic etc) inside the exported function or should they be kept outside if possible.

Comment: You say "search something in mongo". How do you statically know what to search for, does it not depend on the arguments of the `getResult` call?

Comment: so actual method retrieves "today's date articles" from DB. For which all I need is a today's date which i am retrieving inside module instead of passing argument. I didn't want to write a big retrieval logic in my route file so instead i created a separate module where I created the getResult() method and in my routes i am just calling the method after including it.

Comment: Show us real code.  We can't recommend best practice with non-specific pseudo code.

Comment: @G.D: Well if you are only retrieving todays article when loading the module, then you're app won't work any more tomorrow. Therefore you will need to do the fetch from within the `getResults` function, it's that simple.

Comment: @jfriend00 Update the question with actual code.